# Python Selenium encoding issues on get_attribute function

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-crawler

I am using Selenium in Python to crawl the drop-down menu of [this](http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I) page. I used `find_elements_by_css_selector` function and get all the data from the second drop-down menu.

But when I tried to print out both the group number and its matched model name through `model.get.attribute('href')`, the model name written in Korean was broken like below:
`5%EC%8B%9C%EB%A6%AC%EC%A6%88` (which is 5-series in BMW).

I know using 'model.text' returns the only model name, but I also need the group name of each model at the same time.

This is why I used `model.get.attribute('href')` instead of `model.text`.

Please help me to work this out.

Below is my code.

```
enter code here#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

link = 'http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get(link)
sleep(.75)

s = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')

makers = ['아우디', 'BMW', '벤츠']

for maker in makers:
    # open manufacturer layer
    next_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="제조사 선택"]')
    next_elem.click()

    next_elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text(maker)
    print(maker)
    next_elem.click()
    print("clicked maker")
    sleep(.75)

    # open model layer
    next_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="모델 선택"]')
    next_elem.click()

    # select model

    models = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#layer_group ul.list li a")
    for model in models:
        print (model.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `href` attribute for the said title. Try this for listing option value-( if any)

```
 elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@title='모델 선택']").
 for option in elem.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
     print option.text
```